# Sun Directory Server can't connect ldap server

Tags: java, linux, arcgis-server, ldapconnection

I'am installing ArcGisServer for the Java plataform on Centos 5.5 x86_64, this is not a supported platform but I have overcome almost every problem preventing the success of the installation. It uses exhaustively Sun Directory Server. The last error i receive was:

ldap_simple_bind: Can't connect to the ldap server - No route to host

It happens in other applications which makes uses of it, so it seems to be an specific problem of Sun Directory Server on linux and solaris. There is no reported solution. Usually I search the problem as much as I can but this time I have reached my patience and I need it working as soon as posible. I recognize this as an excellent forum because of it's community and quality of answers, ¿can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

The "No route to host" error suggests that the issue is one of network connectivity between your ArcGIS server (the Sun Directory Server component, as you mention) and the LDAP server. So, a few things to examine, in order:

1. Do you have an LDAP server set up and running?
2. Is your LDAP server reachable from your Centos machine outside of the ArcGis server?
3. Is your ArcGis configured with the correct address to the LDAP server - should be in the web.config file? Example below:

   `<connectionStrings>`

   `<add name="ADConnectionString"
   connectionString="LDAP://SERVER_LDAP:389/ou=Sigestredi,o=Sicondef,dc=aplicaciones,o=mdef,c= es" />`

   `</connectionStrings>`

   - *Disclaimer: I don't know anything about the ArcGIS server per se - I'm just diagnosing the "no route to host error" with a few snippets I picked up from some quick searches of the ArcGis forums.*

Answer (score 0):

ArcGIS includes a Sun Directory Server on it, so arcgis server and ldap are on the same machine. The port is set to 62000. When I run the diagnostic tool the DG028 fails:

```
DG028 - check LDAP server: is listening
```

I made a prove using nmap as:

```
nmap localhost -p62000
```

And it says it is opened. I don't know how to verify if LDAP is up and running, the startup log doesn't show anything wrong. I have found a config file named ldap.conf:

```
url ldap://name.subdomain.domain:62000/dc=name,dc=arcgis
admnm agsadmin
```

And my /etc/hosts is:

```
127.0.0.1  localhost localhost
ip_direction  name.subdomain.domain name.subdomain.domain
```

I don't have an alias for "name", so:

```
ping name.subdomain.domain
```

Works

But:

```
ping name
```

Doesn't work

I have never used ldap so I don't know what should be on "dc". Could my hosts file be malformed or is my ldap.conf?

Another information is that the computer I am using is part of a domain. When I installed Centos, /etc/hosts file had an alias for the loopback interface as localhost.localdomain but i removed it.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem, the problem was on my /etc/hosts file. I added an alias for my ip direction:

```
127.0.0.1  localhost localhost
ip_direction  name.subdomain.domain name
```

Then I run the ServerConfig script. This is a successful installation of ArcGIS Server for the Java platform on Linux. Thanks Greg for your guide.